# How to test wildcard sub domains within cloud-9 ide

Tags: dns, cloud9-ide

I am trying to test my express app with vhost for subdomain support. The issue is that the /etc/hosts file does not support regex to route say *.localhost.com to 127.0.0.1. In order to address this, I installed the popular dns server dnsmasq to acquire regex support but I am unable to get it working, and I believe it has to do with the lack of a proper configuration. The dnsmasq *address*  flag was enabled and set to /localhost/127.0.0.1 [as per this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain), I then created an entry within /etc/host -- `127.0.0.1 *.localhost.com` and then in my app I'm listening on process.env.PORT and process.env.IP but no requests show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this on /etc/hosts of your local machine or cloud9 vm?
By default cloud9 redirects all subdomains of your app to the process.env.IP so requests to `subdomain.<workspacename>-<username>.c9users.io` will go to your app with host header set on request, without any modifications to vhosts.

See this cloud9 community question for more details https://community.c9.io/t/how-to-host-multiple-websites-in-one-server/3780

Comment: This did it, thanks. I spent a fair share of my day trying to work it out.